# Woocommerce Add to cart button jumps

Tags: css, woocommerce

For my ecommerce site, when you click on a product and 'add to cart' there's a message that comes up to say "This item has been added to your cart" with a box saying "view cart".

The problem is the "View Cart' button is jumping on a mobile device. (it jumps a little on a desktop too but not as badly). I've checked the css code for the message box and the button and there's nothing I can see that is overriding and making it jump. Does anyone know what might be causing this please?

The page is https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/product/charming-soft-pink-roses/.

The CSS for the message box is -

```
.woocommerce-message.lsx-woocommerce-message-wrap {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #c1e3b2;
    text-transform: uppercase;

.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-info, .woocommerce-message {
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 3.5em;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c1e3b2;
    list-style: none outside;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey add the below style and recheck.

```
@media(max-width:767px){
 .woocommerce-message.lsx-woocommerce-message-wrap{
   display:block;width:100%;
 }
}
```

Comment: No it still jumps.. the view cart button goes to the top right corner first then drops to center bottom